# Why does Circus Baby not tell me to go to Ballora Gallery?

Tags: five-nights-series, fnaf-sister-location

I just recently got into playing Five Night's at Freddy's 5, and have had a small issue when playing Night 2. After making Bidybabs "lose interest", Baby is supposed to tell me to crawl slowly through Ballora Gallery, only stopping if I hear Harry Potter music. However, after making Bidybabs go away, I am stuck under the desk and Baby never tells me anything. Is this a glitch or something? And if I can, do I need to hack the save file to get to the next night?